# Ajax callback. Do not understand the ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am fetching data from a file, in this case it is `/notes.html`. I am trying to store the result of the ajax call in a variable, but it keeps returning undefined, but when I run the function in chrome developer tools, it returns the content of `/notes.html`. Here is my simple code modified to log the data:

```
    var ajax = {};
    ajax.result = Array();
    ajax.fetch = function(urls,datas){
        $.ajax({
            url: urls,
            type: 'post',
            data: datas,
            success: function(data){
                console.log (data);
            }
        });
    }
    ajax.fetch('/notes.html',{});
```

Now here is what I am talking about. If we change `console.log` and make it into a `return`, and then `console.log` the `ajax.fetch` call, we get undefined.

When I save it in `ajax.result` and then call it in chrome dev. tools, the content shows up in chrome dev. tools, but I cannot use it in the base javascript.

The page is [here](http://goo.gl/ixHpZq). It is a blank page, but you can see in the console what it prints out with the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax is a deferred call by nature, so it really doesn't matter what you return from the function, the original fetch already exited and returned undefined a while ago...

you can pass a callback into fetch to solve this:

```
var ajax = {};
var result;
    ajax.result = Array();
    ajax.fetch = function(urls,datas, callback){
        return $.ajax({
            url: urls,
            type: 'post',
            data: datas,
            success: function(data){
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    }
    ajax.fetch('/notes.html',{}, function (data) {
        // execute result related code here to ensure variable already assigned
    });
```

if you do a trace, you'll get the following execution:

1. ajax is declared
2. result is declared
3. ajax is set to `{}`
4. ajax.result is set to a new array (btw you should use [] instead of Array to avoid potential prototype madness)
5. ajax.fetch is set to the function
6. ajax.fetch is called, with an anonymous function serving as the callback
7. $.ajax is called
8. ajax.fetch returns (this is where your undefined comes from, now it will returned a jQuery [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/))
9. success callback is called
10. passed callback is called
11. success callback returns (no way to capture the return value since fetch already returned in 8)
12. [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) callback is code (here you can use your fetched data thanks to closures)

Comment: Thank you. I am thankful to have all of these wonderful people here. I do have one question though. Would this work: http://pastebin.com/k8bxjx42

Comment: as in, would the correct result be returned from the last callback? then no, since it's the same behavior (asynchronous) as $.ajax. perhaps if you tell me what you want to do with result I could help :)

Comment: one thing to note, if you want to adhere to the DRY principle, you can generalize the ajax.fetch function by making it receive the callback function as a parameter. In this case, the done call would probably be unnecesary, if all you're result-related logic is in the passed callback; and you'll have a nicely encapsulated fetch function you can use elsewhere in your code

Comment: ...or you can remove the success prop altogether and call the ajaxSuccess method directly on fetch, like so: `ajax.fetch('/notes.html',{}).ajaxSuccess(...)`. Again, this will abstract out the page specific logic from the generic fetch method

Comment: I just want to be able to automatically build up an array of the results that way I could reference them later with the lest amount of code possible. I would think that it is the most efficient way in javascript, since that is what I use in PHP a lot, and PHP is written in C, I believe the same that the JavaScript engine runs. So I would not think the syntax would have too much of a difference. I am not very good at ajax, I have always had trouble getting it to work right.

Comment: the main thing is to stop thinking about linear execution that returns immediately, and remember that since ajax is asynchonous in nature, you need to hook into it. So instead of thinking about how to store the data, you need to think about when said data becomes available. it'll become available only after the call is responded, and that's what the success/error/done callbacks are for. if you absolutely cannot include the result-specific logic in the success callback then you need to encapsulate said logic in a function and execute it from the success callback, i.e. after it becomes available

Comment: ok, I'll change my answer so the comments section doesn't become more cluttered :P

Comment: I have this: http://pastebin.com/gc4iNrGB is this correct? Can I get the var setting corrected?

Comment: no, but you can move the `alert(data)` (or any logic that needs `data`) inside the callback

Comment: how would I set that to a global var? would I have to use the `window.` syntax?

Comment: you can use `window.varname`, `window['varname']` or simply `varname`, if `varname` isn't declared in the local scope. personally I like `window['varname']`

Answer (score 0):

The call to $.ajax() is returning immediately after making the request, as it is running in asynchronous mode by default. The return value of the $.ajax call is not the return value of the success function. Switch on synchronous behaviour:

```
ajax.fetch = function(urls, datas)
{
  result = null;
  $.ajax({ url: urls,
           type: 'post',
           data: datas,
           async: false,
           success: function(data) { result = data; } });
  return result;
}
```

Or just do this:

```
$.ajax({ url:   urls,
         type:  'post',
         data:  datas,
         async: false }).responseText;
```

Comment: that won't work, since fetch returns before success is called, all it will return is undefined

Comment: Not with `async` set to `false`.

Comment: true, but that would defeat the purpose of making the ajax call in the first place

Comment: I don't think it defeats freddydoggie's purpose at all--he wants to retrieve a file and expects his ajax call to block until his string is available.